# How can I allow a newer .Net assembly to load without manual reconfiguration?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

A vendor supplies an assembly for a piece of hardware I used about six years ago. The end user has replaced the computer and installed the latest version of the drivers.

The problem is that my software wants to see a specific version `2.5.0.0` of the assembly before it loads it and the new version is `2.9.0.0`.

I added a `BindingRedirect` in the executable's config file and it now loads just fine.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="MccDaq"
                        publicKeyToken="a37eefcf5c6ca10a"
                        culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535"
                       newVersion="2.9.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Is there some way to future proof this so that it doesn't fail the next time they install a new version?  I had the reference's `Specific Version` check set to `false` in the original code, but upon review it seems that this is a compile time option and not a run-time setting.

Comment: Just the standard way, providing your user with an installer that deploys *all* of the components you need.

Comment: Does the vendor supply a [publisher policy file](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/introduction-to-publisher-policy-file/)?

Comment: @JohnWu - I did not know about the publisher policy file. That seems to be the correct solution. The vendor does not provide one, I asked them to reconsider. I guess time will tell.

Comment: @HansPassant - We did provide the card's driver CD with the original installation six years ago. In 2019 the customer's IT department went out and got the most recent version of the drivers. So it seems that  without a Publisher's policy file I will have to provide documentation on adding the BindingRedirect.  In fact I will probably add it to the default installation for the future so they can simply edit the version number.

Comment: You have no expectation whatsoever that a future version will be compatible with your code.  So this just creates another problem that is quite a bit harder to solve.  A more productive way to handle it would have been giving them the file(s) that they lost.  YMMV.